# MS ACCESS Fetching data from lookup table in row source of form

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, lookup-tables

I have 2 tables: Projects and Contacts. 
The Projects table has a CONTACT field which is a lookup to the Contacts table.

I have a bound form.

My error: If I use a bound box for CONTACT field, if I update it, it updates the Contacts table and thus all Projects under that Contact are now reassigned to the new one.

I only want to update the current Project to the assigned contact.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you would use a combobox to select the item. the source_control of the combobox would be the field in your project table. The RowSource of the combobox would be a select query from "contact table". try this and let us know where you've got stuck.

Comment: MY SOLUTION:Make the combobox bound to the CONTACT field of the Commitments table... however this functionality prevents me from adding new contacts as it is bound to the lookup table.

Comment: MY SOLUTION:Make the combobox bound to the CONTACT field of the Projects table... however this functionality prevents me from adding new contacts as it is bound to the lookup table.

To enable adding new contact: 
combo box to be bound to the CONTACT from the project table
The row source would be set to query the contacts table (co_id and FullName), the column count set to 2, and the width of the columns set so that the id column doesn’t show 0.

Furthermore, to add new contacts:  you can set the list item edit form to the form you create